# How to show all images extensions using global and count in php?

Tags: php, image

StackOverflow,
I'm having an issue outputting the other image **extension**.Now it's only working with **.jpg** and I want to get the other image extensions from the path.

I tried some ways but I can't figure it out how to make it work.I'm not a professional, still learning.Any tip on how to do this?Thank You.

This is my code:

```
    $files = glob('/home/folder/sub.domain.com/'.$_GET['lang'].'/'.$row['link'].'/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);

        $total = count($files);


        for($i = 1;$i <= $total; $i++){
            $pictures .= '<div class="single_img_container">
 <img src="https://sub.domain.com/'.$_GET['lang'].'/'.$row['link'].'/'.$i.'.jpg"/>
</div>';

        }
```

Comment: Your files are in `$files` yet you are trying to display `$i.jpg`. Loop over the `$files` array and use that instead.

Comment: @jeroen That's what I thought but I read: _"it's only working with .jpg"_. So I think the images have a numeric name. Isn't it Agnes Pandek?

Comment: @Syscall Looping over `$files` would work either way, regardless of how the images are named.

Comment: @jeroen Yes, using the key for index if needed.

Comment: @jeroen Right. The question is not really clear about how `$i` is required.

Comment: @Syscall True, there is probably more as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: @Syscall yes the images are named 1 , 2 ,3 ,4 etc and im getting it from sub.domain via global brace

Answer (score 0):

Your files are in `$files` yet you are trying to display `$i.jpg`. Loop over the `$files` array and use that instead:

```
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $pictures .= '<div class="single_img_container">
      <img src="https://sub.domain.com/'.$_GET['lang'].'/'.$row['link'].'/'.$file.'"/>
</div>';
}
```

Comment: I think `basename($file)` should be better, no?

Comment: @Syscall Probably, and I would use a `htmlspecialchars()` on the other variables. But the idea is clear :-)

Comment: @jeroen I am counting from 1 , for example I have in database description_1, description_2 and the images are 1.jpg , 2.jpg,3.jpg, so i am trying to show description_1 above 1.jpg wich is the first in the article.The problem is that it only  takes the jpg format not the jpeg or others

Comment: @AgnesPandek That does not matter, you should check what `$files` contains as it is all that you need and will get rid bugs that occur when you for example remove an image in the middle.

Comment: @jeroen If I do it like this  it shows 2 links towards image , the one from global and the one from foreach

Comment: @AgnesPandek Check the contents of `$files` and see @Syscall's comment, you might need `basename($file)`.

Comment: @jereon is there a way to do it with if elseif ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
    for($i = 1;$i <= $total; $i++){
        $pictures .= '<div class="single_img_container">
        <img src="https://sub.domain.com/'.$_GET['lang'].'/'.$row['link'].'/'.$i.'.'.$files[$i]->getExtension().'"/>
        </div>';
    }
```

Comment: I think you are mixing `glob()` up with a directory iterator. `glob()` does not return an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by doing this

```
for($i = 1;$i <= $total; $i++){
            if(is_file('/home/folder/sub.domain.com/'.$_GET['lang'].'/'.$row['link'].'/'.$i.'.jpg')){
                $picture = $i.'.jpg';
            }
            elseif(is_file('/home/folder/sub.domain.com/'.$_GET['lang'].'/'.$row['link'].'/'.$i.'.jpeg')){
                $picture = $i.'.jpeg';
            }

    $pictures .= '<div class="single_container"><h3 
   class="top_img_description">'.$row['description_'.$i]. '</h3>'.'<div 
  class="single_img_container"><img 

src="https://sub.domain.com/'.$_GET['lang'].'/'.$row['link'].'/'.$picture.'"/>
 </div></div>';
        }
```

Thank you all.